# MySql database doesn't submit the values of my form

Tags: php, html, mysql

My database doesn't submit my values of my form, when I enter values into my form it shows nothing at all the varchar value columns and at the integer value columns there is a 0.   [After I submit values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQ3UQ.png)

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anyhb.png)

I'm using xampp.

```
   <?php
 error_reporting(0); 


$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root",'',"bwl_db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = 'root123';
$database = 'bwl_db';


$Name =  $_POST['Name'];
$Surname =  $_POST['Surname'];
$Email =  $_POST['Email'];
$Telephone = $_POST['Telephone']; 
$ID_Number = $_POST['ID_Number']; 


$sql="INSERT INTO reg_db (Name,Surname,Email,Telephone,ID_Number) 
VALUES ('$Name','$Surname','$Email','$Telephone','$ID_Number')";



if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}


mysqli_close($con);

error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0)

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>BWL | Registration </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Simple, clean, responsive website built with html5, CSS3, Js, jQuery and Bootstrap">
    <meta name="keywords" content="web, design, html, css, html5, css3, javascript, jquery, bootstrap, development">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500italic,600italic,600,700,700italic,300italic,300,400,400italic,800,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,300,300italic,400italic,600italic,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <!-- Fontawesome  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- responsive css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css"> </head>

<body>

    <div class="registaration-logo">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <img src="images/translogo.png" alt=" ">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <form class="form-registration" action="reg_db.php" method="post">
              <h2> Registration </h2>
        <div class="form-group-row">
            <label for="Name" class="col-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-10">
                <input class="form-control" name="Name" type="text" id="Name" placeholder="Enter Name"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group-row">
            <label for="Surname" class="col-2 col-form-label">Surname</label>
            <div class="col-10">
                <input class="form-control" name="Surname"  type="text" id="Surname" placeholder="Enter Surname"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group-row">
            <label for="Email" class="col-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-10">
                <input class="form-control" name="Email"  type="email" id="Email" placeholder="Enter email"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group-row">
            <label for="Confirm Email" class="col-2 col-form-label"> Confirm Email</label>
            <div class="col-10">
                <input class="form-control"  type="email" id="Confirm Email" placeholder="Confirm email"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group-row">
            <label for="Telephone" class="col-2 col-form-label">Telephone Number</label>
            <div class="col-10">
                <input class="form-control" name="Telephone"  type="tel" id="telephone" placeholder="Enter Telephone Number"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group-row">
            <label for="ID_Number" class="col-2 col-form-label">ID Number</label>
            <div class="col-10">
                <input class="form-control" name="ID_Number"  type="text" id="id-number" placeholder="Enter ID Number"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group-row">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <a href="verify.html" class="btn btn-default1" role="button" type="submit">Submit</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <h3> Disclaimer</h3>
      <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
  </div>
        </div>
 </form>

</body>

</html>


 VERIFY.HTML PAGE
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>BWL | Verify </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Simple, clean, responsive website built with html5, CSS3, Js, jQuery and Bootstrap">
    <meta name="keywords" content="web, design, html, css, html5, css3, javascript, jquery, bootstrap, development">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500italic,600italic,600,700,700italic,300italic,300,400,400italic,800,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,300,300italic,400italic,600italic,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <!-- Fontawesome  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- responsive css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css"> </head>

<body>


   <div class="verify">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>Thank You</h2>
    <p>We will send you your login information when you are verified.</p>
  </div>
       </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you are posting data on same page ?

Comment: Try changing your query to this; $sql="INSERT INTO reg_db (Name,Surname,Email,Telephone,ID_Number) 
VALUES ($Name,$Surname,$Email,$Telephone,$ID_Number)";

Comment: you are getting the for values while printing array like print_r($_POST);

Comment: Thank you, I will try your code

Comment: post your HTML code

Comment: It looks like u don't have a submit button, therefore your form is not submitted, can you show the content of verify.php ?

Comment: What is your file name? reg_db.php ?

Comment: Both php and html are posted, just scroll down

Comment: Lot's of mistakes in this code....

Comment: @Farhad Sakhaei its reg_db.php

Comment: An anchor tag, have a type attribute? That does not look like a valid html, why don't you just have button instead?

Comment: why you are using a tag

Comment: Sorry I'm a rookie

Comment: Is this the right one : $password = 'root123';

Comment: your button should be a <input type="submit" name"any name" value="any value"> don't use a href for submit a post

Comment: You have some values which didn't use those in your connection, like $dbhost, $user, $password, $database - Try using those values or clear them for your mysqli_connect

Comment: @MixiRocking you need to define connection variables **before** `$con` yours connection to database `$dbhost = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = 'root123';
$database = 'bwl_db';` then put your connection `$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bwl_db");` and turn on `error_reporting(1);` to check for errors.

Comment: Its working, thank you everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not using a `submit`-button you are just using a `href` so your data isn't submitted. Change your last line of the form to this:

```
<div class="form-group-row">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input class="btn btn-default1" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", '', "bwl_db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$Name = $_POST['Name'];
$Surname = $_POST['Surname'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Telephone = $_POST['Telephone'];
$ID_Number = $_POST['ID_Number'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO reg_db (Name,Surname,Email,Telephone,ID_Number) 
VALUES ('$Name','$Surname','$Email','$Telephone','$ID_Number')";



if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}


mysqli_close($con);
}

?>
```

```
<head>
    <title>BWL | Registration </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Simple, clean, responsive website built with html5, CSS3, Js, jQuery and Bootstrap">
    <meta name="keywords" content="web, design, html, css, html5, css3, javascript, jquery, bootstrap, development">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500italic,600italic,600,700,700italic,300italic,300,400,400italic,800,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,300,300italic,400italic,600italic,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <!-- Fontawesome  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- responsive css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css"> </head>

<body>

    <div class="registaration-logo">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <img src="images/translogo.png" alt=" ">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <form class="form-registration" action="" method="post">
        <h2> Registration </h2>
        <div class="form-group-row">
            <label for="Name" class="col-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-10">
                <input class="form-control" name="Name" type="text" id="Name" placeholder="Enter Name"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group-row">
            <label for="Surname" class="col-2 col-form-label">Surname</label>
            <div class="col-10">
                <input class="form-control" name="Surname"  type="text" id="Surname" placeholder="Enter Surname"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group-row">
            <label for="Email" class="col-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-10">
                <input class="form-control" name="Email"  type="email" id="Email" placeholder="Enter email"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group-row">
            <label for="Confirm Email" class="col-2 col-form-label"> Confirm Email</label>
            <div class="col-10">
                <input class="form-control"  type="email" id="Confirm Email" placeholder="Confirm email"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group-row">
            <label for="Telephone" class="col-2 col-form-label">Telephone Number</label>
            <div class="col-10">
                <input class="form-control" name="Telephone"  type="tel" id="telephone" placeholder="Enter Telephone Number"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group-row">
            <label for="ID_Number" class="col-2 col-form-label">ID Number</label>
            <div class="col-10">
                <input class="form-control" name="ID_Number"  type="text" id="id-number" placeholder="Enter ID Number"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group-row">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="btn btn-default1" role="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h3> Disclaimer</h3>
                <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: possible undefined index trouble

Comment: Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\BWL\reg_db.php on line 5
Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\BWL\reg_db.php on line 23

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\BWL\reg_db.php on line 24
Error:

Comment: @MixiRocking Do you have enough permissions on your db?

Comment: @WasteD permissions or  privileges?

Comment: @MixiRocking normally the user root has the permission to change Things but maybe you changed something

Comment: @MixiRocking set your database credentials

Comment: @Mario Used static values instead of variables.

Answer (score 1):

**Problems:**

1. You should have a if statement to check if the form is submitted or not
2. Your submit link is not for submitting your form, You should have a submit button to send your form data to the current page
3. You have some values which didn't use those in your connection, like $dbhost, $user, $password, $database - Try using those values or clear them for your mysqli_connect

I recommend you to read this example:
[Insert Data Into MySQL Using MySQLi and PDO](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Could you check to see if the type of data stored in columns telephone and id_number is INT if so u should change the statement

```
$sql="INSERT INTO reg_db (Name,Surname,Email,Telephone,ID_Number)VALUES ('$Name','$Surname','$Email','$Telephone','$ID_Number')";
```

To

`$sql="INSERT INTO reg_db (Name,Surname,Email,Telephone,ID_Number)VALUES ('$Name','$Surname','$Email',$Telephone,$ID_Number`)";

Also change the action attribute of form element to point to your page itself as the php code in the current page only

```
<form class="form-registration" action="" method="post">
```

Please include the details of the table so that we could get a better idea of the problem.

Answer (score -3):

Its probably due to the fact that you are sending your forms post variables to reg_db.php when the code is on the same file.

Change

```
<form class="form-registration" action="reg_db.php" method="post">
```

To...

```
<form class="form-registration" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
```

Comment: If he change this the code run without bug? Did you see full question and his code?

Comment: this could not be the solution

Comment: yes, this it the most clear cut error to why there is nothing making it to the database.

Comment: First of all He did't submit a form.., then how you try to fix for inserting db?